# Sourcing bash script while running a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am making some tests by running a bash script like `/home/travis/test_build.sh`. I have a separate script `checkout.sh` which sets the environmental variables (and I can not call it before the test_build.sh). So, inside of `/home/travis/test_build.sh` i source the it: `. ./checkout.sh`. But after the execution of `checkout.sh` using echo I see that the variables are set back to the initial values(empty). Is there a way to fix it?

Short example of  `/home/travis/test_build.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what is 0: $0"
set -x
. ./checkout.sh
echo "COMP_ARCH=$COMP_ARCH"
echo "FRAME_BASE=$FRAME_BASE"
```

Short example of  `checkout.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what is 0: $0"
set -e
export COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
eval `scramv1 runtime -sh` # link scramv1 is set to some other script which is not mine, starts with `#!/bin/sh` and which is supposed to set some additional variables as FRAME_BASE
echo "COMP_ARCH=$COMP_ARCH"
echo "FRAME_BASE=$FRAME_BASE"
```

The output after execution of `/home/travis/test_build.sh` would be then:

```
what is 0: /home/travis/test_build.sh
what is 0: /home/travis/test_build.sh
COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
FRAME_BASE=/home/1234/wer/base
COMP_ARCH=slc6_amd64_gcc493
FRAME_BASE=
```

Comment: You mean after execution of `test_build.sh` is done everything is back to normal?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing both scripts, but you may be sourcing `checkout.sh` inside a subshell.

Comment: What is the output of `scramv1 runtime -sh` ?